# How to fit exponential decay using a series of exponential functions?

Tags: exponential-function, approximation, regression

With two arrays $x$ and $y$ giving exponential decay as given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3938042), an exponential function in the form $y = Ae^{-Bt} + C$ is fitted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938548) answer. I want to generalize to the fitting function in the form
$$y = 1 - (A_1(1 - e^{-B_1t}) + A_2(1 - e^{-B_2t}) + A_3(1 - e^{-B_3t})+\dots);$$

basically using $2, 3, ..., N$ exponential terms. Any comments on how to do it?

My data is slightly different from a pure exponential decay (as described in the above links) and a single exponential term is not sufficient to fit the data properly.

Comment: [Nonlinear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_regression).

Comment: I have read that fits like this are very difficult because all the exponentials look very much like each other, so the fit parameters are poorly defined.  There are particular combinations of the parameters you are quite insensitive to.

Comment: Out of curiosity… If you have data pairs $(x_i, y_i)$, is it the case that $0 < y_i < 1$?

Comment: I can always normalize the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle of a method which can be generalised is given in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

Case of one exponential : Pages 16-17.

Case of two exponentials : Page 72.

The case of three exponentials is not explicitely treated in the paper. In addition see below :

[image]

On the same way one could treat the cases of more exponentials. But this would probably be of no practical use because the deviations due to the scatter of the experimental data. Even with three exponentials the numerical calculation becomes doudtful. Too many parameters to optimise in the model supposes to have big data with low scatter.

For more robustness, better compare to a model with two exponential instead of three. See below :

[image]